# Using python's pack with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pack

I'm trying to use the pack function in the struct module to encode data into formats required by a network protocol.  I've run into a problem in that I don't see any way to encode arrays of anything other than 8-bit characters.

For example, to encode "TEST", I can use format specifier "4s".  But how do I encode an array or list of 32-bit integers or other non-string types?

Here is a concrete example. Suppose I have a function `doEncode` which takes an array of 32-bit values.  The protocol requires a 32-bit length field, followed by the array itself.  Here is what I have been able to come up with so far.

```
from array import *
from struct import *

def doEncode(arr):
    bin=pack('>i'+len(arr)*'I',len(arr), ???)

arr=array('I',[1,2,3])
doEncode(arr)
```

The best I have been able to come up with is generating a format to the pack string dynamically from the length of the array.  Is there some way of specifying that I have an array so I don't need to do this, like there is with a string (which e.g. would be `pack('>i'+len(arr)+'s'`)?

Even with the above approach, I'm not sure how I would go about actually passing the elements in the array in a similar dynamic way, i.e. I can't just say `, arr[0], arr[1], ...` because I don't know ahead of time what the length will be.

I suppose I could just pack each individual integer in the array in a loop, and then join all the results together, but this seems like a hack.   Is there some better way to do this?  The array and struct modules each seem to do their own thing, but in this case what I'm trying to do is a combination of both, which neither wants to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = pack('>i', len(arr)) + arr.tostring()
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Should I worry about the `len(arr)*'I'` part for large values of len(arr)?